# Jest error with vanilla JS submodules: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, git-submodules

I have a function that uses modules from a submodule and when I try to run the test it fails with `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

[image]

If I run the code calling from a normal file the module loads and execute, so I'm sure the issue is on my Jest configuration, not on my code, but looks like the `import` statement inside my submodule is failing with Jest.

The submodule is on the `.helpers` folder.

**Translator/index.js**

```
import { Excel } from './excel.js'
import { Auth } from '../.helpers/Helpers/auth.js'
import { secret } from '../.helpers/Helpers/secret.js'

/**
 * Read the request and add it to the queue
 * @param {object} context The context from Azure
 * @param {{ contentBytes: string, translations: { Title: string, Term: string }[] }} req The request object
 */
async function start (context, req) {
  ...
}
```

**Translator/package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
        "local": "node ./Translator/local.js",
        "check-package": "npm-check",
        "update": "npm-check -u",
        "postinstall": "submodules-install"
    },
    "jest": {
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/.jest/init.js",
            "<rootDir>/.jest/console.js"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "Translator/**/*test.js"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
          "<rootDir>/.helpers/"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text",
            "cobertura",
            "html"
        ],
        "reporters": [
            "default",
            "jest-junit"
        ]
    },
    "jest-junit": {
        "outputDirectory": "coverage",
        "outputName": "test-results.xml",
        "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
    },
    "submodules": [
      ".helpers"
    ],
    ...
```

If I move the submodule files to the src folder, Jest runs normally :(

This is the `package.json` of the submodule.

**.helper/package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
        "build": "tsc",
        "check-package": "npm-check",
        "update": "npm-check -u"
    },
    "jest": {
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/.jest/init.js",
            "<rootDir>/.jest/console.js"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text",
            "cobertura",
            "html"
        ],
        "reporters": [
            "default",
            "jest-junit"
        ]
    },
    "jest-junit": {
        "outputDirectory": "coverage",
        "outputName": "test-results.xml",
        "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
    },
    ...
}
```

I don't use Babel or any transpiling tool, it's pure vanilla JavaScript, but I have a `.babelrc` file so Eslint on VSCode understands private methods, but I just noticed it has something about "tests" on it, so it might be related.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "shippedProposals": true
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what configs I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I renamed `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` and it is working. I didn't change anything else!

I'm just leaving this question here so if anyone comes to something similar they will know the solution.